# Decrypting Kubernetes secret using the encryption key

Tags: kubernetes, openssl, encryption

I have a toy Kubernetes cluster with Encryption at rest enabled using the `abs-256-cbc` provider; I have not used any vault here for `kms` simulating the problem. This means the encryption key is in a plain text file on the master node.

```
apiVersion: apiserver.config.k8s.io/v1
kind: EncryptionConfiguration
resources:
  - resources:
      - secrets
    providers:
      - aescbc:
          keys:
            - name: key1
              secret: c2VjcmV0IGlzIHNlY3VyZQ==
      - identity: {}
```

Assuming the encryption key `c2VjcmV0IGlzIHNlY3VyZQ==` is leaked, is there any chance to decrypt the secrets stored in the `etcd`?

Example:

Secret creation:

```
k create secret generic secret1-no-encryption --from-literal foo="admin@123"
secret/secret1-no-encryption created
```

Reading the secret from `etcd` when its **NOT** encrypted:

```
sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://192.168.122.191:2379 --cert=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-test-kube-controller-1.pem --key=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-test-kube-controller-1-key.pem --cacert=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem get /registry/secrets/default/secret1-no-encryption
/registry/secrets/default/secret1-no-encryption
k8s

v1Secret▒
▒
secret1-no-encryptiondefault"*$3d45ddaa-2e34-4605-92d2-ad2ad31592692▒▒▒▒`
kubectl-createUpdatev▒▒▒FieldsV1:,
*{"f:data":{".":{},"f:foo":{}},"f:type":{}}B
foo     admin@123Opaque"
```

Attempt to read secret when the etcd is encrypted:

```
sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://192.168.122.191:2379 --cert=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-test-kube-controller-1.pem --key=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-test-kube-controller-1-key.pem --cacert=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem get /registry/secrets/default/secret2-with-encryption
/registry/secrets/default/secret2-with-encryption
k8s:enc:aescbc:v1:key1:n%-▒▒▒▒▒Ԩ▒qB▒x'V▒F▒y`l▒_X▒n
                                                  8#EEg▒!▒▒Mnk▒S▒▒KQ▒▒F▒NyJ▒$▒J▒▒Q`▒3m▒▒_▒▒U▒!7ZP▒bm▒x▒▒▒\▒{▒)e▒4▒Q-L▒#▒▒▒ձ▒<8▒▒ndd}Ҏ▒|1k▒▒>▒▒▒J▒R▒.▒▒c▒mɹ▒Q▒D▒▒Z▒▒H▒4▒~.▒F▒▒j▒▒C▒י%▒▒8▒▒▒8▒ޥE`Kp;▒%▒▒/e▒▒▒▒{.m▒c͍.˻▒▒1▒▒▒ݑ=u▒{▒▒~▒KP▒▒v7ϋ'▒{d]#
                     +▒<M
```

**Question:**

Is knowledge of the `encryption key` enough to decrypt the etcd contents? **if** just the `encryption key` is not enough to decrypt the content(perhaps `IV` is required), why bother using `KMS`(except key rotation)? Is there any way `IV` can also be leaked?

Is it authoritatively safe to say just the key leak could not cause the decryption of the `etcd` contents?

Comment: The encryption key leak will not cause the decryption of the "etcd" contents directly as it has many security layers but it will act as a tool which can cause a data breach and spread malware.

Comment: "_Is it authoritatively safe to say just the key leak could not cause the decryption of the `etcd` contents?_" someone would also need the database entries and be able to decrypt them like in [How can I encrypt / decrypt AES-256 CBC with OpenSSL?](https://superuser.com/a/1361462/754490) or [How to use OpenSSL to encrypt/decrypt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056298/6771046).